# Get property values without using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a list which contains thousands of objects. 
I want to get the values of specific properties in each iteration, but I don't want to use reflection because of performance penalty.
What other choices do I have?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? By "a list of objects" do you mean literally a List<object>?

Comment: No, it's a List<MyObject>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have all of the objects in question implement an interface that exposes the properties you are interested in, and have a list of that interface type.  This not only improves performance over reflection, but ensures static verification of type safety of your code.

Comment: this sounds OK. what about Dictionary which the key is the prop name and the value is a delegate to the prop. is that better?

Comment: I'd say no, as then you're back to losing your static type safety.